# Is the DC power input of a motor driver equal to the active power of a 3-phase motor on the output?

Tags: power, motor, three-phase

It is unclear to me how the DC power that is inputted into a motor driver is related to the 3-Phase power going to the motor from the driver. Is it correct to assume that the DC input power is equal to the active power of the motor? If not, is it the apparent power or is it something else entirely?

Comment: _”active portion of the apparent power”_ This is just active power. Difference would be the losses.

Comment: DC input to the motor driver = mechanical output power of the motor + heat lost in the motor + heat lost in the driver + other insignificant losses like noise, vibration, electromagnetic radiation.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I corrected the wording of my question to better explain what I mean. Is it possible to create a mathematical relationship between the 3-Phase power in the motor to the DC input power. For example if we know that the input is 48V, 5A (240W) what is this power equal to in the 3-Phase Power analysis.

Comment: Pac = Pdc * eta where Pac is real AC power, Pdc is dc power, and eta is the efficiency of the motor driver. Eta will be less than 1 whenever the motor is doing useful mechanical work.